# pytest: Parametrizing from function output / from directory structure

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, regression-testing, parametrized-testing

I am trying to build testcase parameters and expected outputs from a directory structure. The directory structure is as follows:

```
__init__.py
foo.py
testing/
├── test_foo/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── case-0001/
│   │   ├── input_1.json
│   │   ├── intput_2.json
│   │   └── output.json
│   ├── case-0002/
│   │   ├── input_1.json
│   │   ├── intput_2.json
│   │   └── output.json
│   └── test_fooFunc.py
```

I already have written a function, let's call it **`makeIO(..)`** that takes files from each test case and returns a tuple of the format: `([input_1_contents, input_2_contents], [output_contents])`.

What I am struggling with is getting that tuple to be passed into **`test_foo.py`**. Here's what I have so far:

```
@pytest.fixture
def makeIO():
    ...
    return IOtuple

IOtuple = makeIO(..)


@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", IOtuple)
def test_two(test_input, expected):
    assert foo.fooFunc(test_input) == expected
```

**The weird part:** Everything works fine and tests pass **if and only if** I remove the **`@pytest.fixture`** decorator from **`makeIO()`**. If I leave it there, I get this error: `Fixture "makeIO" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly, but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.`

Is there any more pythonic and elegant way of achieving what I am aiming for? Would any alternate directory structure or function be recommended? Also, I think I'm just missing the point of fixtures and would appreciate a clarification about why and how they''re used (docs didn't clarify it for me).

---

Disclaimer: I am completely new to pytest, so I apreciate any and all helpful resources that would flatten the learning curve.

Comment: That's correct: you can't call a fixture directly, you have to pass it to a test or another fixture. For the parameters, you just use an ordinary function, because the decorator is evaluated at load time - this is the standard way to do it. As for fixtures generally: the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html) has also a few examples, and there a lot of answers on SO for concrete questions regarding fxtures.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `@pytest.fixture` from my function did exactly what I wanted, and the function can be now be parametrized though values obtained from that function.